# Correct way to get value from relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
SELECT l.journal_id, %s              
FROM account_move_line AS l
  LEFT JOIN account_journal j ON (j.id = l.journal_id)
WHERE l.state <> 'draft'
AND l.journal_id IN (%s)
AND (l.account_id = j.default_credit_account_id OR
     l.account_id = j.default_debit_account_id)
```

and I get error

> ```
> column l.state does not exist
> LINE 17: WHERE l.state <> 'draft'
> ```

`account_move_line` does not have `"state"` but it have relation to `account_move` which has `state`. relation is `move_id`

so how can I write it correctly? I tried

```sql
WHERE l.move_id.state <> 'draft'
```

but I get an error

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "move_id"
LINE 17: WHERE l.move_id.state <> 'draft'
^
```

Basically I need `move_id` that related to `account_move_line state <> 'draft'`

Comment: you need a join to account_move table, I guess something like `JOIN account_move m ON l.move_id=m.id`. After you put this between `FROM ` and `LEFT JOIN` make a filter `WHERE m.state <> 'draft'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below Query:

```
SELECT l.journal_id, %s              
FROM account_move_line AS l
INNER JOIN account_move am ON l.move_id = am.state_id
  LEFT JOIN account_journal j ON (j.id = l.journal_id)
WHERE am.state <> 'draft'
AND l.journal_id IN (%s)
AND (l.account_id = j.default_credit_account_id OR
     l.account_id = j.default_debit_account_id)
```

Comment: "operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 16: ... INNER JOIN account_move am ON l.move_id = am.state
^

Comment: You need to use primary key of account_move table in JOIN reference. I used am.state_id for your example only.